# Python cImage scale image by 1/2

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python function using the cImage module that receives the image im1 with an arbitrary size of nxm, returns im2 which has the size of (n/2)x(m/2).

I'm not really sure how to do this. The function must be named `MakeHalfImage(im1)`.

If anyone could point me on the right track, that'd be great!

Thanks!

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Can have a look at pillow for image processing or wand.

Comment: @Donny P - This is a homework assignment for my CompSci class.

Comment: @Marcin - I'm forced to used the cImage module.